# understand the use of the Hölder inequality in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following  result is the interior gradient estimate for harmonic functions.

> Suppose $u$ is harmonic in $B_{1} .$ Then there holds
> \begin{align*}
> \sup _{B_{1 / 2}}|D u| \leq c \sup _{\partial B_{1}}|u|
> \end{align*}
> where $c=c(n)$ is a positive constant, and $B_r$ is denoted the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$  centering
> the  origin with radius $r$.

I'm having trouble understanding some part in the proof of the proposition and it states:

> By taking $\varphi=\eta^{2}$ for some $\eta \in C_{0}^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$ with $\eta \equiv 1$ in $B_{1 / 2},$ we obtain by the Hölder inequality
> \begin{align*}
> \Delta\left(\eta^{2}|D u|^{2}\right)=& 2 \eta \Delta \eta|D u|^{2}+2|D \eta|^{2}|D u|^{2} \\
> &+8 \eta \sum_{i, j=1}^{n} D_{i} \eta D_{j} u D_{i j} u+2 \eta^{2} \sum_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(D_{i j} u\right)^{2} \\
> \geq &\left(2 \eta \Delta \eta-6|D \eta|^{2}\right)|D u|^{2} \geq-C|D u|^{2}
> \end{align*}
> where $C$ is a positive constant depending only on $\eta .$

I get trouble understanding how the Hölder inequality was applied here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks

Comment: you’re welcome!